# Binary-Decimal Negative bit set

Tags: c++, binary, decimal

How can I tell if a binary number is negative?

Currently I have the code below. It works fine converting to Binary. When converting to decimal, I need to know if the left most bit is 1 to tell if it is negative or not but I cannot seem to figure out how to do that.

Also, instead of making my Bin2 function print 1's an 0's, how can I make it return an integer? I didn't want to store it in a string and then convert to int.

EDIT: I'm using 8 bit numbers.

```
int Bin2(int value, int Padding = 8)
{
    for (int I = Padding; I > 0; --I)
    {
        if (value & (1 << (I - 1)))
            std::cout<< '1';
        else
            std::cout<<'0';
    }

    return 0;
}

int Dec2(int Value)
{
    //bool Negative = (Value & 10000000);

    int Dec = 0;
    for (int I = 0; Value > 0; ++I)
    {
        if(Value % 10 == 1)
        {
            Dec += (1 << I);
        }
        Value /= 10;
    }

    //if (Negative) (Dec -= (1 << 8));

    return Dec;
}

int main()
{
    Bin2(25);
    std::cout<<"\n\n";
    std::cout<<Dec2(11001);
}
```

Comment: C++ does not support binary literals or printing numbers in binary format. To handle binary representation, you should be using strings. Note that `Dec2(11001) != Dec2(00011001)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking for negative value incorrectly. Do the following instead:

```
bool Negative = (value & 0x80000000); //It will work for 32-bit platforms only
```

Or may be just compare it with 0.

```
bool Negative = (value < 0);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if bitwise-and for sign-bit works with all the compilers.

Comment: Yes I realized it, that's why I added the second option.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs Nor will it work for a 64-bit. The latter obviously will, however.

Comment: Yes, so the first version should be warned against which we just did. how clever us three are :)

Comment: The second version only works if I'm using the number 25 in the OP. If I use: 11110100 which is -12 in binary, it will not work. It will spit out 244 unless I set Negative to true because I know it's a negative binary number.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just compare it to `0`. Should work fine and almost certainly you can't do this in a manner more efficient than the compiler.

Comment: Only works for some numbers.. It works for 11001 which is 25. But it does not work for 11110100 which is -12.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames so you only use 8 bit numbers, not the full 32 bits of an integer?

Comment: Yes. All the binary numbers are eight digits in length.

Comment: @Please add this to your question - it never mentions having 8 bit numbers that use the 8-th bit as sign bit.

Answer (score 2):

I am entirely unclear if this is what the OP is looking for, but its worth a toss:

If you know you have a value in a signed `int` that is supposed to be representing a signed 8-bit value, you can pull it apart, store it in a signed 8-bit value, then promote it back to a native `int` signed value like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // signed integer, value is 245. 8bit signed value is (-11)
    int num = 0xF5;

    // pull out the low 8 bits, storing them in a signed char.
    signed char ch = (signed char)(num & 0xFF);

    // now let the signed char promote to a signed int.
    int res = ch;

    // finally print both.
    printf("%d ==> %d\n",num, res);

    // do it again for an 8 bit positive value
    //  this time with just direct casts.
    num = 0x70;
    printf("%d ==> %d\n", num, (int)((signed char)(num & 0xFF)));
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
245 ==> -11
112 ==> 112
```

Is *that* what you're trying to do? In short, the code above will take the 8bits sitting at the bottom of `num`, treat them as a signed 8-bit value, then promote them to a signed native `int`. The result is you can now "know" not only whether the 8-bits were a negative number (since res will be negative if they were), you also get the 8-bit signed number as a native `int` in the process.

On the other hand, if all you care about is whether the 8th bit is set in the input `int`, and is supposed to denote a negative value state, then why not just :

```
int IsEightBitNegative(int val)
{
    return (val & 0x80) != 0;
}
```